# RequireJS: data-main won't load the file

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I am simply converting my small project into nodejs. But for some reason, the requireJS file - the one where you define the JS you will use in your project is not loading.

Here is my structure ...

[image: Folder Structure]

the `ng-app` is where I make the front-end for the site. I use gulp to process them into html and js and placed to `ng-dist`

Here is what my server.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/ng-dist'));

app.listen(3000);
```

When I go to my browser, it is rendered just as expected.

[image]

But it appears that my `require.js` file is not being read as stated in the `data-main` attribute.

[image]

Here is what `require.js` file looks like.

```
require.config {
    baseUrl :'app/'
    paths   : {
        angular     : '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min'
        ngRoute     : '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-route.min'
        ngAnimate   : '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-animate.min'
        router      : 'routes'
        directives  : 'directives/ref'
        services    : 'services/ref'
        coreModule  : 'config'
        jQuery      : '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min'
        uikit       : '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.21.0/js/uikit'
    }
    shim: {
        ngRoute:{
            deps:['angular']
        },
        ngAnimate:{
            deps:['ngRoute']
        },
        coreModule:{
            deps:['ngAnimate']
        },
        uiKit:{
            deps:['jQuery']
        }
    }
}

define ['coreModule'], ->
```

This is basically the same thing in my PHP project. I don't have an idea why require is not reading my `require.js` file and load my scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[data-main](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main) is a RequireJS module to load. In Your case RequireJS try to load `/require.js.js`. Remove the extension, and rename the file to `app.js` (`require.js` is ambiguous). Finally:

```
<script data-main="app"
        src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.17/require.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: I can't use require as a fillename?

Comment: No. This is only example. `require.js` is ambiguous (require.js as RequireJS and require.js as config). Name it freely, but so that, that name was clear.

Comment: I originally have data-main="require" but it didn't work. But in any case, thanks!!!

Comment: Share Your code on GitHub if You can. I try to look at this.